# Why the loop does not want to continue

Tags: python, ruby

The function asks a question, the answer to which should be YES or NO. It takes the text of the question and returns the letter "y" or "n". I have a Python code, I need to transform it to Ruby.

```
#Python code 
def ask_yes_no(question):
    response = None
    while response not in ("y", "n"):
        respone = input(question).lower()
    return response
```

What did i do

```
# Ruby code
def ask_yes_no(question)

    guessed_it = false
    response = ""

    puts question
    loop do

        unless (response == ("y" || "n"))  || guessed_it

            response = gets.downcase
            return response #&& guessed_it == true

        end

        break if guessed_it == true 
    end
end

ask_yes_no("
How is the weather?")
```

Comment: That should be raising a SyntaxError in `response == ("y" || "n")`. Try with `response == "y" || response == "n" || guessed_it`.

Comment: works but does not continue the cycle

Comment: if I enter another letter, he must again ask "y" or "n"

Comment: fixed indentation code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of your Ruby code isn't the same as the Python version, and would be just as incorrect in Python as it is in Ruby.

`("y" || "n")` is a boolean operation on two strings; since all strings are true in Ruby, the result is the first string. So therefore the result of the whole boolean operation is also true, so the `unless` is false, and the block is never entered.

You can use `include?` to do the same as the Python version:

```
unless ["y", "n"].include?(response) || guessed_it
```

but the whole Ruby version can be translated much more directly:

```
def ask_yes_no(question)
    puts question
    response = nil
    until ["y", "n"].include?(response) do
        response = gets.downcase.strip
    end
    response
end
```

Comment: can you briefly say what he is doing  (!) exclamation point    ???

Comment: Yes, `until` is clearer, changed. @sstwg `!` is "not".

Comment: response is return response? 7 line

Comment: `response = gets.downcase.strip until %w[y n].include?(response)` would collapse four lines into one. Allowing you to remove `response = nil` up to `end` (of `until`).

Comment: @sstwg [By default, a method returns the last expression that was evaluated in the body of the method.](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Return+Values) You don't have to use `return`, only if you want to return early.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Ruby regex's.

```
def ask_yes_no(question)

    until (print question; gets.chomp.downcase =~ /y|n/) do
    end

    $~.to_s

end
```